# Finding all pairs of elements in an array that sum to a target value

Tags: javascript, array

Is there a shorter way and does not involve nested for loops?

```
const checkIfSumFromTwoNumbers = (arrayOfNum, targetValue) => {
    let found = [];
    let result = [];

    for (let value of arrayOfNum) {
        if (found[targetValue - value] === true ) {
            result.push({[arrayOfNum.indexOf(value)]: value, [arrayOfNum.indexOf(targetValue-value)]: targetValue - value});
        }
        found[value] = true;
    }
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>No, each number requires a second pass to determine whether combined with an existing one it is a match - doesn't mean it can't be short though e.g.</strike>

```
const checkIfSumFromTwoNumbers = (arrayOfNums, targetValue) => 
  arrayOfNums.reduce((matches, val) => {
      const target = arrayOfNums.find(x => (val + x) === targetValue);
      target && matches.push([val, target]);
      return matches;
   }, [])
```

I was actually ignorant to the fact your code actually works which means it can be done in one pass :) here's a slightly neater / more concise version of what you already have:

```
const checkIfSumFromTwoNumbers = (arrayOfNum, targetValue) => {
  const seen = {};
  return arrayOfNum.reduce((matches, val) => {
    const delta = targetValue - val;
    seen[delta] && matches.push([delta, val]);
    seen[val] = true;
    return matches;
  }, []);
};
```

Comment: First time using code review and this was a great answer. Thank you so much for taking the time to write that out.

Comment: @ChaseNorton no worries, just realised that the current implementation would result in duplicates e.g. if your target value was 7 and you had an array of 1-5, 2+5 & 5+2 would match - presumably you wouldn't want this?

Comment: A single pass solution is [possible](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/176669/113168)

Comment: @wOxxOm actually, with a little tweak that solution would work. At the minute it just matches on the first sum - I may be able to adapt my own answer to be one pass now that I can see it has duplicates.

Comment: Instead of using an object literal as a map, why not use a `Set` object?

Comment: @kamoroso94 No particular reason, probably not any real advantages using one over the other in this particular example.

Comment: Well like my old shop teacher used to say, you should use the right tool for the right job.  Now that we have `Map` and `Set` objects to work with, using an object literal as such is kind of hacky.

Comment: @kamoroso94 I don't disagree, however, an object isn't necessarily the _wrong_ tool here. `Map` _might_ be more efficient but probably only when you get into the 1000s of iterations.

Comment: @kamoroso94, I am just starting out with JS, so did not know about the Set and Map objects. Do you mind showing me how you would use Set to do this problem?

Comment: @ChaseNorton code would be more or less the same other than swapping out the `seen` object for a `Set`. When adding to the set use `seen.add(x)` and when checking `seen.has(x)`.

Comment: @James Thats really cool...thank you. Going to look into it more now

Comment: @ChaseNorton [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) are a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned shorter, the same array can be used for found and result:

```js
const f = (a, t) => a.reduce((r, v) => (r[v - t] && r.push([t - v, v]), r[-v] = 1, r), [])

const f2 = (a, t) => a.reduce((r, v, i) => 
    (r[v - t] + 1 && r.push({ [r[v - t]]: t - v, [i]: v }), r[-v] = i, r), [])

const a = [3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4], l = console.log, j = JSON.stringify
l(j( f(a, 6) ))
l(j( f2(a, 6) ))

// .slice() can be added to the result to make a copy without the "hidden" items:
l(j({ ...f(a, 6)         }))
l(j({ ...f(a, 6).slice() }))
```

Hacky code golfed answers like this are probably not very appropriate on Code Review, so hopefully it's not too much against the rules. A bit of explanation:

In JavaScript, `Array` is actually an object that uses positive integer properties. For Example:

```js
a = []
a[1] = 1
a.b = 'c'
a[-1] = -1
a[0.1] = 0.1
a[/./g] = /./g

console.log(a)      // [undefined, 1] - only the positive integer properties

console.log({...a}) // { "1": 1, "b": "c", "-1": -1, "0.1": 0.1, "/./g": /./g }
```

So this part `r[-v] = 1` adds a key `-v` to the array, and `r[v - t] &&` checks if the array has entry with key `-(target - value)`, and if the entry's value evaluates to true.

Another part is the [Comma Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator#Processing_and_then_returning). In JavaScript `result = (expresion1, expresion2)` evaluates both expressions and returns the result of the last one.